# Transparent background actionbar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to custom  an ActionBar with  my file PNG. Something like this.
It looks ugly. 
how do I can do actionbar as PNG file.
Everybody please help me.

Comment: Like What? Have you tried any thing before?

Comment: i tạo ra tập tin và custom_actionbar.xml Trong MAinActivity // tạo thanh hành động được đầu ra như hình trên.
View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
  TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView
    .findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
  mTitleTextView.setText("");

  mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
  mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);